# How to make a task call name using macro concatenation in SystemVerilog?

Tags: macros, concatenation, verilog, system-verilog

In my SystemVerilog test, I'm trying to make a task call name by using macros.

If `AAA_BLK` is defined, I want the task call name replaced as `test_aaa_proc();`, and the same way for `BBB_BLK` and `CCC_BLK`.

```
`ifdef AAA_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME aaa
`elsif BBB_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME bbb
`elsif CCC_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME ccc
`endif

task test_aaa_proc();
...
endtask

task test_bbb_proc();
...
endtask

task test_ccc_proc();
...
endtask

virtual task body();
  test_``BLK_NAME``_proc ();
endtask
```

But, it fails with below errors.
Would you please advise?

```
        test_``BLK_NAME``_proc ();
              |
xmvlog: *E,EXPCPD 
 expecting a valid compiler directive [16(IEEE)].
        test_``BLK_NAME``_proc ();
                      |
xmvlog: *E,MISEXX 
 expecting an '=' or '<=' sign in an assignment [9.2(IEEE)].
        test_``BLK_NAME``_proc ();
                        |
xmvlog: *E,EXPCPD 
 expecting a valid compiler directive [16(IEEE)].
        test_``BLK_NAME``_proc ();
                             |
xmvlog: *E,NOTDIR 
 `_proc: not a recognized directive or macro [2.7.3][16.3.1][16(IEEE)].
```

Answer (score 0):

The ``` `` ``` syntax can only be used in the macro **definition**, not in the macro **call**.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 22.5.1 *`define*.

You can create a new macro which will resolve into the task name that you want to call.  Then, you can call that new macro from the `body` task.  Here is a complete runnable example:

```
module tb;

`define AAA_BLK

`ifdef AAA_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME aaa
`elsif BBB_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME bbb
`elsif CCC_BLK
  `define BLK_NAME ccc
`endif

`define TEST_TASK(block)  test_``block``_proc

task test_aaa_proc();
    $display("%m");
endtask

task test_bbb_proc();
    $display("%m");
endtask

task test_ccc_proc();
    $display("%m");
endtask

task body();
    `TEST_TASK(`BLK_NAME);
endtask

initial body();

endmodule
```

This prints:

```
tb.test_aaa_proc
```